# Is there a general term for "non-universal" iOS binaries?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ipod-touch, universal-binary

I'm currently developing both universal and "non-univeral" apps for iOS. As you may know, "universal" apps are those that run on iPhone, iPad, and iPod touch. I'm curious if there's a general term for apps that run on only one type of iOS device.

It's mainly for some documentation I'm writing for clients. I'd like to sound less redundant when possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That probably would be "iPhone app", "iPad app" and "iPod touch app" respectively. No?

Comment: That is my guess, but I'm not sure if there's an official or unofficial all-encompassing term.

Comment: Agreed. Or if OP wants a different word to describe the general thing, how about "targetted" or "specific" binary.